# hash indexes on replicated times ten db

Tags: timesten

I have have a replicated times ten database.  I need to reset the page size of a number of hash indexes.   when I update the page sizes it breaks replication and takes 10 hours to rebuild replicated databases.  There has to be some way to up update hash index size that does not break replication.  Oracle is telling my dba, " if you update index sizes you have to rebuild replication."  It seems BAD idea to go 8+ hour without a failover.  currently doing (we tried setting replication level to 2.  hand no effect)  the following resets index size for primary key to 23244 pages

```
ALTER SESSION SET ddl_replication_level = 1;
ALTER TABLE MYSCHEMA.employee SET PAGES = 23244; 
......
ALTER SESSION SET ddl_replication_level = 3;
```

has anyone updated hash index sizes without rebuilding replication???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According oracle the only solution other than rebuilding replication.  Is:

- Disable replication.
- Run DDL on primary node.
- Run ddl alter statements secondary nodes.
- restart replication

  Not sure if we still need ddl_replication_level settings.  We will try next week